# Why wouldn't 'this' keyword work on an event handler function that uses parameters?

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

```
var x = document.getElementById('id');
x.addEventListener('click', function() {
  check(x, 5);
}, false);

function check(x, length) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('ids');
  if (this.value.length < length) { //doesn't work
    msg.innerHTML = 'not long enough'
  }
}
```

`if(x.value.length< length)` works. I don't fully understand how to implement the `this` keyword.

Comment: `this` only "works" in the function that is the event handler, which is the anonymous function in your case, not `check`.

Answer (score 3):

The `this` inside check will point to the `window`. You have to [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the function `check` by binding `this` into it to accomplish your task,

```
  x.addEventListener('click',function(){
    check.call(this, x,5);
  }, false);
```

Comment: Unless the `check` function code is in strict mode, in which case `this` would be `undefined`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You are talking about the `this` inside of `check`. Right? Yeah that is correct. this would not be `window`, it would be `undefined`. - In strict mode

Comment: Yep, I was referring to the `check` function.